# Error while parsing JSON response using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
[
    {
        "dueAmount": 400,
        "paidAmount": 0,
        "balanceAmount": 400,
        "invoiceNo": "VA019_203829",
        "planName": null,
        "schemeName": null,
        "connectionStatus": null
    }
]
```

I'm getting this response from postman. But when i try to read these contents from my page, it returns "**Undefined**"

```
$http({ 
method:'POST', 
url: 'http://10.10.1.200:8081/SelfCare/customer/getInvoiceDetails',
headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }, 
data: JSON.stringify(getID)
       }).then(function (response) { 
        $scope.invoice = response.invoiceNo;
        alert($scope.invoice);
}
```

its always alerting **undefined**

Comment: Try `response.data[0].invoiceNo`. Your response will be encapsulated into `data`.

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` in `then`. It should work with `response.data[0].invoiceNo`.

Comment: use `console.log` than `alert`.

Comment: thank you so much... its working...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a change replace `$scope.invoice = response.invoiceNo;` by `$scope.invoice = response.data[0].invoiceNo;`

Your response will get encapsulated into `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$scope.invoice = response.data[0].invoiceNo;
```

Instead of

```
$scope.invoice = response.invoiceNo;
```